# Temp table updates is slower then normal table in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I have a situation where updates on my temp table is slow. Below is the scenario

1. Created temp table in session  for every session,first time temp table created and then going forward doing insert,update and delete operations this operations until session ends only.
2. First i'm inserting the rows and based on rows i'm updateing other columns. but this updates is slow compared to norma table. i checked the performance by replacing temp table whereas normal table taking around 50 to 60s but temp table is taking nearly 5 mins.
3. I tried analyze on temp table, then i got the improved performance. when im using analyze the updates are completed in with 50 seconds.
4. I tried Types also, but no luck.
5. Record count in temp table is 480

Can anyone help to imprrove the performance on temp table with out analyze OR any alternative for bulk collect and bulk insert in user defined types

All the above ooperations i'm doing in postgresql.

Comment: You should create index(es) to speedup the update and delete and avoid inserting too long/large values in the columns.

Comment: While creating the table, same time indexes ar created on few columns. those columns we are using where condition. coming to values, just we inserting almost number values only. infact after analyze table only update operation is speed up. Here my concern is on few  number of records(consider records count 480)  update is taking around 1 to 3 mins.   my query look like  with cte_vw as (select x.* from X join y on x.a=y.b where x.call_date > date '01/01/2020') update temp_work A set col_1=b.col_2 from cte_vw where A.COL_3=B.COL_3.  consider  xand y volume like  around 1 millions records.

Comment: Well, the CTE is not indexed so if you are JOIN-ing your temp table with the CTE then probably the JOIN is slow. Did you looked at the execution plan?

Answer (score 0):

The lack of information in your question forces me to guess, but if all other things are equal, the difference is probably that you don't have accurate statistics on the temporary table. For normal tables (which are visible to the public), autovacuum takes care of that automatically, but for temporary tables, you have to call `ANALYZE` explicitly to gather table statistics.

Comment: is it stats required on temp table where record count is around 480 ?

Comment: You *always* need statistics for accurate estimates and good execution plans.